# Webparts in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

what is webparts in asp.net? a simple example on webparts. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web parts :  Web Parts is a framework built into ASP.NET 2.0 for building highly customizable portal-style pages.?User can do customized user settings in browser for each user.Like minimize ,maximize ,close etc for each control in browser .

http://www.csharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a_anajwala/Building_WebParts.mht08042005042119AM/Building_WebParts.mht.aspx?ArticleID=62ffd1b4-98fa-41cc-9512-9b0637e91eed

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/01/10/liberty.html

Note : Web parts is a browser memory eater :)

Answer (score 2):

Web Parts allow building dynamic portal-like UI with drag/drop end-user customization.

From [ASP.NET Web Parts Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhy9ewf1.aspx):

> ASP.NET Web Parts is an integrated set of controls for creating Web sites that enable end users to modify the content, appearance, and behavior of Web pages directly from a browser.

Examples of web portals are [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig), [My Yahoo!](http://my.yahoo.com/), and [Windows Live Personalized Experience](http://my.live.com/).

## Trivial example

```
<asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
</asp:WebPartManager>

<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server">
  <ZoneTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello world!" Title="Hello"  />
  </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>

<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server">
  <ZoneTemplate>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Title="Calendar" />
  </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>
```

[image: screenshot]

## Resources

- [What Are Web Parts?](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/01/10/what-are-web-parts.html?page=1) by Jesse Liberty (introduction to ASP.NET 2.0 WebParts)
- [Personalize Your Portal with User Controls and Custom Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300767.aspx) from September 2005 issue of MSDN Magazine
- [ASP.NET 2.0 Web Parts in Action](http://www.manning.com/neimke/) - book by Darren Neimke